# Transfer media from iOS device to Windows with vb.net

Tags: ios, windows, vb.net, directory, file-transfer

I have a project in vb.net and I need to transfer files from iOS folder to my PC when device is connected via USB.

I can't access to the virtual DCIM folder and so I tried with PortabledeviceCOM, but it's in C++ and then also if I can see all stored files and transfer one or all of them, they are listed with just an undefined name "o18", "o1A" and so on while I need to identify them to be able to find a way to transfer just the last captured file (picture/video).

Is there something I can use on vb?

I also read the second answer posted here [Can images be read from an iPhone programmatically using CreateFile in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11017615/can-images-be-read-from-an-iphone-programmatically-using-createfile-in-windows) but I can't understand how to use that code.

Comment: Yeah, the linked answer should answer your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can images be read from an iPhone programmatically using CreateFile in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11017615/can-images-be-read-from-an-iphone-programmatically-using-createfile-in-windows)

Comment: So what part of the solution exactly are you struggling with?

Comment: I can't understand how it works. For example there is the function "Function EnumNamespaceItems(oItem As Object, SrcCPath As String, SrcDPath As String, folderLevel As Integer) As Integer
" but which values I have to use for these variables "SrcCPath" or "oItem" or "folderLevel", from where I can extrapolate these data? I'm searching for something like this CopyHereFileWait("Computer\Apple iPad\Internal Storage\DCIM\100APPLE\HRSR4270.MP4", "C:\ciao\HRSR4270.MP4")